# Why --(-val) is not working?

Tags: c++

```
int val = -10;
cout << ++(-val) << endl;
```

Output should be `11`. But it gives me an error.

Comment: `-val` isn't a lvalue.

Comment: -val will make it 10

Comment: --val will make it 10

Comment: Can you increment a literal like `10++;`? It's the same effect.

Comment: What would be the use case? You *can*  write `val = -val + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is "lvalue required as increment operand". This means that it's just a value; it does not represent a particular object like "val" anymore so trying to change it makes no sense to the compiler.